# Android: Creating tablerow in an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities

Activity 1 and Activity 2

I am trying to create a table from activity 1 and im trying to create it in Activity 2

```
private TableRow createRow(int y){
    TableRow row = new TableRow(Activity2.context); <---- this one?
    row.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    for (int x = 0; x < COL_COUNT; x++) {
        row.addView(createImageButton(x,y));
    }
    return row;
}
```

How can i make this possbiel thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Each Activity is responsible for its own UI. You ought to populate the `Intent` which starts `Activity2` and then have `Activity2`'s `onCreate()` build out the UI.